# MySQL query... Importing to new table, want to leave dupes behind

Tags: mysql, wordpress, greatest-n-per-group

I've got a Wordpress site with MySQL and I've would up with a lot of duplicate data due to a poorly written plugin that imports data into this site.  I've fixed the plugin, and I am not working on getting rid of the duplicate data.  Due to there being millions of dupes, I've decided to INSERT data into a new table rather than DELETE. I've been able to INSERT all of the data without duplicates but I don't know how to structure a query to avoid pulling in duplicates.

See the below example data.  There are 3 "charge_0" lines per post ID, but there should only be one.  How can I select the first 'charge_0' per unique post_id?

| meta id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 15 | charge_0 | 1000 |
| 25 | 15 | charge_0 | 1000 |
| 26 | 15 | charge_0 | 1000 |
| 27 | 16 | charge_0 | 3000 |
| 28 | 16 | charge_0 | 3000 |
| 29 | 16 | charge_0 | 3000 |

I haven't tried anything yet. I spent a few hours researching and I'm am lost.  It seems like maybe I group by post ID but I am not sure.  I'm a frontend dev by trade and this is a bit too far out of my comfort zone.

Comment: This type of question has been answered numerous times. Read answers in the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Comment: I think you can create a unique constraint and add one or multiple columns to it. [see this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: I figured it out, I think I was assuming it was more complicated than it actually was.  

SELECT * FROM wp_17_postmeta WHERE `meta_key` = 'charges_0' GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY `meta_id` DESC

This returns only the first charge_0 per post_id.